# Flutter web - mouse wheel up zooms page - problem

Tags: flutter, zoom-sdk, flutter-web-browser

In Flutter 3.16 I'm facing an issue with web app.
When scroll with mouse wheel down, everything is ok.
But when want to go back, page zooms up. It is very annoying!

How to prevent this, customers are complaining!

I tried all I found to put in  in index.html to prevent this, nothing worked.

Comment: Hi, plese note, remove the [zoom-sdk] tag. It's intended for Zoom Meetings API